# How can I assign multiple bones to one vertex group?

Tags: armature, bones, vertex-groups

Although having almost a year of experience, I still suck at Blender.
I recently figured out that you can assign a bone to a vertex group by naming it the same name as the vertex group.
How could I assign multiple bones to one vertex group?

Thanks

Comment: It would be much more accurate to say that you assign vertices to bones, and that assignment is made via vertex groups, rather than that you assign bones to vertices or VGs.  "What owns what" is backwards from how you're thinking about it, and that makes this question hard to understand.  Could you maybe share info about your practical end goal and what it is you hope to accomplish by what you're asking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy a vertex group (it will duplicate the selected group) and change its name so that it has the same as another bone:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Geometry Nodes to copy vertex weights from one group to the other:

[image]

Loading from *Named Attribute* also works:

[image]

Using *Store Named Attribute* will not work, though, it will set all weights to 0.

**Make sure your Geometry Nodes modifier is above the Armature modifier:**

[image]